# Los metodos POST no son ejectuados en la web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

tengo el siguiente código:

```
public static void EnviarDatos<T>(string url, T data, EmpresaData empresa)
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

                var stringContent = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var result = client.PostAsync(url + "?identificador=" + empresa.Identificador, stringContent).Result;


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }
```

Y el codigo de mi controlador contiene estos metodos:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Turnos(List<Turnos> Turnos, string identificador)
    { ...... }

 [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Sectores(List<Sectores> Sectoress, string identificador)
        { ..... }
```

Y no ejecuta ninguno de los 2. La url es correcta.

Creo que tiene que ver con que los parametros son casi iguales y puede que el PostAsync se confunda.

¿Que sera?

Comment: si lo ejecutas desde una tool como ser PostMan ingresa en alguno de los action ?

Comment: ademas porque defines un catch vacio ? sin ninguna accion dentro de este, eso es una pesima practica, podrias tener un error y nunca te entera, no sera que hay un exception pero no lo estas visualizando

Comment: El catch está vacío para no mostrar el código acá solamente.

Comment: Y en PostMan me dice esto:
"Multiple actions were found that match the request", nombrando a continuación los metodos Post que he publicado.

(por cierto, sos famoso acá en mi trabajo (siempre encontramos tus respuestas por internet xD, gracias)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el problema es de multiples match cuando resuelve que action deberias poder separarlo indicando el routing

Analizando la documentacion

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

veras que se puede usar el atributo `[Route]` para indicar la url que tendra cada action

```
[Route("api/turnos")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Turnos(List<Turnos> Turnos, string identificador)
{ ...... }

[Route("api/sectores")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Sectores(List<Sectores> Sectoress, string identificador)
{ ..... }
```

entonces la url quedarian

```
http://sitio/api/turnos
http://sitio/api/sectores
```

ambos con `POST` pero lo separas segun que datos quieres recuperar

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné modificando el WebApiConfig.cs de la carpeta App_Start cambiando a esto:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa como estas mapeando las url de tu web api para multiples acciones de un mismo llamado 
 por default el route template se declara

```
 routeTemplate:"api/{controller}/{id}"
```

debe estar declarado de la siguiente manera:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "API Default",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```